# Show that every Jordan matrix has a cyclic vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Is my following reasoning correct?

Since an $n\times n$ Jordan matrix has rank $n-1$ (because we can only make the last row the zero row), its geometric multiplicity is 1, which means the matrix has a cyclic vector. How would you prove the sentence in the title in a more mathematical way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a Jordan matrix?

Comment: In any case, the argument you wrote is not only not very mathematical: it does not make much sense, as far as I can tell :-|

Comment: I don't think it's true unless there's only one Jordan block for every characteristic value.